# Drupal 8 - Convert view results into 2 columns

Tags: php, drupal, view, drupal-8

I have a search view which results are in a single column. I would like to move only couple of fields to the second column. is this possible?

My views-view-fields--mytestview.html.twig code is as below:

```
{% set index = 0 %}
<div class='row'>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
       {% for key, field in fields -%}

        {% if index == 0 or index == 5 %}
        <div>
        {% endif %}

            <span {{ field.label_attributes }}>{{ field.label }}{{ field.label_suffix }}</span>

            <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="{{ tooltips[key] }}">
              <span {{ field.element_attributes }}>{{ field.content }}</span><br/>
            </a>

        {% if index == 4 or index + 1 == fields | length  %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}

        {% set index = index + 1 %}
      {%- endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is making all the fields appear in a single column. I would like to move the google map and the link below it to second column. Any help? Attaching my current view screenshot here....

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like you are on the right track doing it within the template. What exactly is not working? Remember that viewing the view preview on the views config page will not be using your template (as it is using the admin template by default)